# Cannot open Scala IDE for Eclipse 4.5 (Neon)

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, eclipse-neon

I recently installed the latest version of Scala IDE for Eclipse (v 4.5, Neon) and when I open Eclipse now I get the following error:

"See the log file
/Applications/eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1490205382383.log"

This is the contents of my log file:

```
    !SESSION 2017-03-22 17:54:53.260 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0-vfinal-2016-12-13T10:59:29Z-Typesafe
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/Justin/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/Justin/.eclipse_keyring

This is a continuation of log file /Applications/eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1490205293646.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2017-03-22 17:54:58.533

!ENTRY org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-03-22 17:54:58.533
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.platform [242]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.intro; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.intro; bundle-version="3.5.1.v20160829-1558"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.intro [265]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20151127-1241"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"; version="0.0.0"
              org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations [66]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2017-03-22 17:54:58.533
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core [71]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui 2 0 2017-03-22 17:54:58.535
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui [298]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.12.1.v20160823-0925"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.ide [263]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.1.v20160819-2118"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.workbench [277]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                     org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [63]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                            org.eclipse.e4.core.di [65]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20151127-1241"
                                   org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations [66]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20160509-1032"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                            org.eclipse.e4.core.services [68]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20160504-0909"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; version="0.0.0"
                            org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [64]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui [255]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.1.v20160819-2118"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="[3.10.100,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="3.12.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.jface [193]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline; bundle-version="3.8.101.v20160816-1954"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.ui.views"; version="0.0.0"
       org.eclipse.ui.views [274]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
```

The log file goes on like that for quite a while so I havent posted the whole thing.

I cant seem to find any reference to this issue online other than:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/823236/

and that solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is release 4.6, release 4.5 is Eclipse Mars. It looks like the code you are trying to install probably wants Eclipse Neon and also requires Java 8.